# loop through all values from col A that are not not in col B

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code to loop through only those rows in range1(AA:AB) whose value in cell AA is not found in Col A.

eg

```
A
1
2
4

AA AB
1  Jon
3  Bob
4  Frank
5  Hank
```

In this example I need to loop through rows containing Bob and Hank only (2 iterations)

Comment: And do what...have you tried anything yet? Please post what you have so far and someone will assist you in modifying your code that isn't working.

Comment: @Marshall I agree - this is not a homework creation service! (a homework editing service maybe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub cycle()

On Error GoTo Unmatched

Set used_range = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
For Each Line In used_range.Rows
    Key = Cells(Line.Row, 2).Value
    If (Key <> "") Then
        x = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Key, used_range, 1, False)
        End If
    Next Line
Exit Sub

Unmatched:
MsgBox (Cells(Line.Row, 2).Value & " " & Cells(Line.Row, 3).Value)
Resume Next

End Sub
```

Some notes - I used columns B and C (index 2 and 3) for my test - substitute the appropriate column index numbers for your spreadsheet

Put the thin gs you need to do in the code after `Unmatched`: